# Number of matrices with mutually distinct rows

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm trying to tackle the following question:

> Find the number of $m\times n$ matrices of $0$'s and $1$'s with mutually distinct rows.

I thought about inclusion-exclusion, but it gets me nowhere. Also, I'm afraid that I don't understand the term "mutually distinct rows"? does it mean that each row of the matrix is different?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just $2^m (2^m-1) \ldots (2^m-n+1)$? Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @md5, would you mind to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand "mutually distinct rows" means that the rows are pairwise distinct. Thus if you choose the rows one by one, there are $2^m$ choices for the first row (all elements of $\{0,1\}^m$), $2^m-1$ choices for the second row (all elements of $\{0,1\}^m$ except the first row), etc.

Hence in overall it gives $2^m (2^m-1) \ldots (2^m-n+1)$ such matrices.